# Get API request not working in Jmeter with a "+" sign

Tags: java, api, get, jmeter, postman

There is a get request which is filtering through `+` while trying to access from the browser and its working.

But when trying to do the same in case of Jmeter or postman its not working.

The request which is working from the browser is in below format.

```
/jon/doe/foo/baar/Number+123456789
```

How can I achieve the same in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

If you can successfully execute the request in browser you should be able to record it using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way of doing this is using [JMeter Templates Feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

     [image]
   - Select HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"

     [image]
2. Prepare your browser for recording. Refer its documentation with regards to how to configure it to use proxy. I would recommend going for [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), just like JMeter it's free and open source, moreover it has separate proxy configuration which is not derived from the operating system.

   - From `☰` menu choose `Preferences -> General -> Network Proxy -> Settings
   - Use `localhost` as the proxy host and `8888` as the proxy port. Use the proxy for all protocols with no exceptions like

     [image]
3. Execute your request in browser
4. JMeter will save the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) under the [Recording Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)
5. Inspect request and response details using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

Answer (score 0):

'+' is a special symbol and you need to encode it: `/jon/doe/foo/baar/Number%2B123456789`

Jemeter has a function to do it in runtime, [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode):

> `__urlencode` : Function to encode a string to a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
>   string.
>
> For example, the string `${__urlencode(Word "school" is "école" in french)}`
>
> returns `Word+%22school%22+is+%22%C3%A9cole%22+in+french`.